# Where are Samsung's "Gallery" app's automatic "tags" stored and how can they be used downstream (i.e. in non-Android photo mgmt / dam software)?

Tags: gallery, exif

Samsung's "Gallery" does a fantastic job at automatically / on its own assigning "tags" to photos, making it easy to find photos with certain keywords (e.g. "sunset" or "furniture" or what not). Where exactly are these tags stored and will they be preserved / usable downstream, i.e. in non-Android photo management / digital asset management software?

---

Related links:

- https://www.howtogeek.com/302672/how-to-view-and-edit-photo-exif-data-on-android/
- https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/samsung-photo-gallery-exif-tags-keywords-on-images.3991507/
- https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=11951.0
- **[Where are extra keyword tags for photos stored?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25757/where-are-extra-keyword-tags-for-photos-stored)**

Comment: Most photo management system don't modify the image to store such tags, instead they maintain an own database. Not sure if Samsung gallery also works this way.

Comment: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/128743/where-are-samsungs-gallery-apps-automatic-tags-stored-and-how-can-they-be